# How to generate a Hebrew PDF in react that includes a table?

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, hebrew, jspdf-autotable

I have been searching the whole internet for hours, I need a PDF generator that supports Hebrew! I need to have a table in the PDF too.
I have tried JSpdf, but I get the text litters fliped הלימ instead of מילה.
I used JSpdf's autoTable to make my table, but I didn't manage to have Hebrew in the table, not even flipped (I get garbage).

I'm open to any suggestion not only JSpdf, I need anything that works.

Here's my code:

David-normal.js:

```js
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
var font = '<here comes a very long string of the fone>';
var callAddFont = function () {
  this.addFileToVFS('David-normal.ttf', font);
  this.addFont('David-normal.ttf', 'David', 'normal');
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
```

reportGenerator.js:

```js
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import "jspdf-autotable";
import "../components/David-normal.js";


// Date Fns is used to format the dates we receive
// from our API call
import { format } from "date-fns";

// define a generatePDF function that accepts a reports argument
const generatePDF = reports => {
  //initialize jsPDF
  const doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.addFont("David-normal.ttf", "David", "normal");
   doc.setFont("David"); // set font
   doc.setFontSize(12);




  // define the columns we want and their titles
  const tableColumn = [ "שם עובד", "מספר פרויקט", "תאריך דיוח", "כניסה", "יציאה", "תיאור"];
  // define an empty array of rows
  const tableRows = [];

  // for each report pass all its data into an array
  reports.forEach(report => {
    const reportData = [
      report.worker_id,
      report.project_id,
      report.reporting_date,
      report.start_time,
      report.end_time,
      report.description,
      // called date-fns to format the date on the report
      format(new Date(report.reporting_date), "yyyy-MM-dd")
    ];
    // push each reports's info into a row
    tableRows.push(reportData);
  });
  // startY is basically margin-top

  doc.autoTable(tableColumn, tableRows, { font: 'David', align: 'right', isSymmetricSwapping: true, isInputVisual: true, isOutputVisual: false });
  const date = Date().split(" ");
  // we use a date string to generate our filename.
  const dateStr = date[0] + date[1] + date[2] + date[3] + date[4];
  // reports title.
  let text = "דוח שעות:"
  doc.text(text, 100, 10, {align: 'right', isSymmetricSwapping: true, isInputVisual: true, isOutputVisual: false});
  // we define the name of our PDF file.
  doc.save(`report_${dateStr}.pdf`);
};

export default generatePDF;
```

Waiting for your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code, in an indirect way, I added the Styles to the text and the autoTable:

```js
  doc.autoTable(tableColumn, tableRows, {styles: {font: "David", align: 'right', isSymmetricSwapping: true, isInputVisual: true, isOutputVisual: false}});
doc.text(text, 100, 10, {styles: {font: "David" }});
```

And made a reverse function to fix the letters:

```js
function fix(str){
   return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Then I called it whenever I know there's Hebrew for example:

```js
let text = fix("דוח שעות:");
```

Unfortunately, my solution flips English words too.

Answer (score 0):

**August 2023**

Well, I started like you, but in the end it turned out that the solution is simpler. Maybe it didn't exist yet when you asked the question, but it should be here for the benefit of those who come across the question on Google.
jsPDF's `setR2L` function should be used.

```
   const doc = new jsPDF();
   doc.addFont("David-normal.ttf", "David", "normal");
   doc.setR2L(true);
   // doc.autoTable(tableColumn... // the rest
```

To avoid the problem of flip English words (or, for example, numbers) I used your function for the opposite purpose:

```
function fixEn(str) {
   if (/[א-ת]/.test(String(str))) return str;
   return String(str).split("").reverse().join("");
}
```